# How to redirect # urls to #! urls automatically in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I am using this configuration to enable `/#!/foo` style URLs. This also breaks `/#/foo` style URLs. How should I configure Angularjs to automatically 'redirect' `/#/foo` to `/#!/foo`?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $urlRouterProvider.when for redirection and attach a handler function to it,

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/#/\w',['$location', function ($location) {
   $location.path('/#!/'+$location.path()); 
}]);
```